# How to avoid recompiling header files

Tags: c++, compilation

My single C++ file includes many header files from various libraries such as MKL and template libraries. Compiling this single file every time takes a long time due to the many include statements. I tried separating the include statements in a single file, making an object file out of it, and linking it during  the compilation of the main file, but it seems the compiler doesn't recognize the definitions of the objects and functions that are defined in the header files.
So, how can I save the compilation time of these header files?

Comment: which compiler/platform do you use?

Comment: If your compiler supports precompiled headers using this feature can help reduce the need to recompile the headers every time you build your code.

Comment: I use intel compiler on linux machine, does it support precompiling? I also can't install ccache utility since I don't have root access.

Comment: Do you need to compile the file every time?  Did one of the dependent header files change?  At my shop, we only rebuild at night by an automated server.  The developers usually only compile files that changed or one of their dependencies changed.

Comment: @tarek: you don't need root access to install `ccache`; you could compile it and configure it to run in your `$HOME

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Precompiled headers:**

What you are doing does sound like it would benefit heavily from precompiled headers (pch's).  The intel compiler does support pch's, as you can see here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522754.

**Installing tools without root permissions**

You can still experiment with ccache to see if that will help your situation -- it can make a huge difference in cases where units do not need to be recompiled, which happens surprisingly often.  The path to doing this is to install ccache locally.  Generally this can be done by downloading sources to a directory where you have write access (I keep an install folder in my home directory) , and then following the build directions for that project.  Once the executable are built, you'll have to add the path for the executable to your path -- by doing

```
export PATH=$PATH:the-path-to-your-compiled-executables.
```

in BASH.  At that point ccache will be available to your user.

A better explanation is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges

**CMAKE, cotire, etc**

One final point -- I haven't read the docu for the intel compiler's pch support, but pch support generally involves some manual code manipulation to instruct the compile which header to precompile and so on.  I recommend looking in to managing your build with CMAKE, and using the cotire plugin to experiment with pch.

While I have gripes about CMAKE from a software engineering perspective, it does make managing your build, and especially experimenting with various ways to speed up your build, much much easier.  After experimenting with pch's, and ccache, you could also try out ninja instead of make and see if that gets you any improvement.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! Precompiled headers (-pch option) indeed made a difference. I installed ccache and did not notice that it makes any improvement in the compilation time with or without pch.